# How can I search through the attendees of a Facebook event? (might need FBML)

Tags: facebook

**Context:** I administer a Facebook "event" to check whether my friends are safe after the Japan earthquake. People invited their friends and now with [10000 attendees](https://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=159815784072458) it is impossible to browse through to check whether your friend is attending. We need a search feature.

**Question: How can I search through the attendees of a Facebook event?**
I can create a Facebook application if it is really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start here `https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/events?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]` in your browser

USER_ID is either the username (facebook.com/username) or their UID.

That should give you the most recent events of that user. Not a 100% method though (I guess if you made an app you would be able to get the correct permissions etc.)

The other way will be the FQL query way.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&query=SELECT rsvp_status from event_member where uid = [UID] and eid = 159815784072458
```

159815784072458 being the Event ID for your event. I tried it against users I know for events they attended and the fql seems to be working better than the Graph for now.

All of these queries were done though the browser.

Comment: How do I get the access token?

Comment: To get the access token, the easiest is to open this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
When you are logged in on facebook, an access_token will be shown. (You might need to enable some developers function on your account)

Comment: (Via a flag): "I believe with the updates of permission event attendees is no longer accessible"